# CMD Batch - for /f or Set /p X=<File.txt not working on larger UTF-8 File

Tags: batch-file

Really confused with this one. I need to replace some characters in a simple text file UTF-8. I have the following code and it works create on small files (1kb) but for some reason when I run it on a 19kb file I get a 0kb output. The file types identical, there is just 1 line of data in each, there are no escape characters etc. in the files.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%f in (C:\Users\CHRW\Desktop\EDILocalTest\Downloads\*) do (

    for /f  "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in (C:\Users\CHRW\Desktop\EDILocalTest\EDIFileCounter.txt) do set "filecounter=%%i"

    set "zero=000000"

    if /i !filecounter! GTR 9 set "zero=0000"
    if /i !filecounter! GTR 99 set "zero=000"
    if /i !filecounter! GTR 999 set "zero=00"
    if /i !filecounter! GTR 9999 set "zero=0"
    if /i !filecounter! GTR 99999 set "zero="

    set "filecounterpadded=!zero!!filecounter!"


    SET "output=C:\Users\CHRW\Desktop\EDILocalTest\Output\"

     for %%a in (%%f) do (
        set "outputfile=!output!!filecounterpadded!-%%~na.edi"
    )

    (for /f "delims=" %%z in (%%f) do (

        set "line=%%z"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "line=!line:'=^!"

        echo(!line!
        endlocal
        ))>> !outputfile!

        rem del %%f
        break > C:\Users\CHRW\Desktop\EDILocalTest\EDIFileCounter.txt
        set /a "filecounter=!filecounter!+1"    
        echo filecounter:!filecounter!>> C:\Users\CHRW\Desktop\EDILocalTest\EDIFileCounter.txt

    )


 )
```

I've also tried loading all the content into a file using this, which works better but it just outputs the first 1026 character for some reason:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%f in (C:\Users\CHRW\Desktop\EDILocalTest\Downloads\*) do (

    set /p content=<%%f

    for /f  "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in (C:\Users\CHRW\Desktop\EDILocalTest\EDIFileCounter.txt) do set "filecounter=%%i"

    set "zero=000000"

    if /i !filecounter! GTR 9 set "zero=0000"
    if /i !filecounter! GTR 99 set "zero=000"
    if /i !filecounter! GTR 999 set "zero=00"
    if /i !filecounter! GTR 9999 set "zero=0"
    if /i !filecounter! GTR 99999 set "zero="

    set "filecounterpadded=!zero!!filecounter!"


    SET "output=C:\Users\CHRW\Desktop\EDILocalTest\Output\"

     for %%a in (%%f) do (
        set "outputfile=!output!!filecounterpadded!-%%~na.edi"
     )

    set "content=!content:'=^!"

    echo !content! >> !outputfile!

    break > C:\Users\CHRW\Desktop\EDILocalTest\EDIFileCounter.txt
    set /a "filecounter=!filecounter!+1"    
    echo filecounter:!filecounter!>> C:\Users\CHRW\Desktop\EDILocalTest\EDIFileCounter.txt   

 )
```

Thanks in advance, 
Chris

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with batch, rather than with a tool that is better designed for this purpose, such as `sed` or `awk` (or even PowerShell)?

Comment: It's part of a larger script, which includes FTP, SFTP etc. plus I have limited access to what I can install, I may have to look at powershell if I can't fix this method

Comment: Plus I'm familiar with batch and have a deadline - I'm not familiar with the other but will look into learning them

Comment: Are you sure that you have a single line of content? Is it possible that you have multiple lines using none Windows `CRLF` line endings and you're viewing it using a method which doesn't properly recognise those?

Comment: I'm 99% it's on a single line, but even if it was on two lines or more I should have caught this in the second method?

Comment: Just found out set /p has a limit of ~1023 characters.

Comment: Yes, and `for /F` limits lines to about 8190 bytes. And be aware that UTF-8 files may contain zero-bytes, which may cause additional trouble in batch scripting. So all in all, batch is definitely the wrong choice here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like all non-hidden UTF-8 encoded text files in folder `%UserProfile%\Desktop\EDILocalTest\Downloads` should be copied to folder `%UserProfile%\Desktop\EDILocalTest\Output` with replacing all occurrences of `'` by `^` inside each file and with file name prepended with an incremented number with exactly six digits.

This is an easy to achieve task with using [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) written by **Dave Benham** which is a batch file / JScript hybrid to run a regular expression replace on a file using JScript.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
if not exist "%~dp0jrepl.bat" goto EndBatch

set "SourceFilePattern=%UserProfile%\Desktop\EDILocalTest\Downloads\*"
if not exist "%SourceFilePattern%" goto EndBatch

set "OutputPath=%UserProfile%\Desktop\EDILocalTest\Output"
md "%OutputPath%" 2>nul
if not exist "%OutputPath%\" goto EndBatch

set "FileCounter=1"

for %%I in ("%SourceFilePattern%") do (
    set "FileNumber=00000!FileCounter!"
    set "FileNumber=!FileNumber:~-6!"
    call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "'" "\x5E" /XSEQ /F "%%I" /O "%OutputPath%\!FileNumber!-%%~nI.edi"
    set /A FileCounter+=1
)

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

The batch file **JREPL.BAT** must be stored in same directory as the batch file with the code above. For that reason the batch file checks first if **JREPL.BAT** really exists in directory of the batch file.

Next is checked if any file to process exists in source folder at all.

Then the output folder is created in case of not existing with folder existence verification.

The incremented number is initialized with value `1`.

The command **FOR** searches in specified source folder for non-hidden files matching the wildcard pattern. The full qualified file name of each found file is assigned to loop variable `I`.

Note: A file name with one or more `!` is not correct processed by this batch file because of enabled [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

There is inside the loop `00000` concatenated with the current file counter value.

From this string is assigned only the last six characters to environment variable `FileNumber`.

The batch file calls now **JREPL.BAT** to case-sensitive replace any occurrence of `'` by `^` specified with its hexadecimal code value in current source file with writing the result into output folder with the incremented file number with six digits in file name at beginning.

Last command in loop increments the environment variable `FileCounter` by `1` using an arithmetic expression.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains also `%~dp0` ... drive and path of argument 0 being the batch file itself.
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `jrepl.bat /?`

See also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)).

Comment: I actually found jrepl.bat before your answer, but that is exactly what I did and it worked perfectly - great little script! Thanks for your answer